# KeyEvent Outside of application

Tags: java

So I am trying to toggle a checkbox with a key, which is working but only when I have the application in focus, I would like to toggle it when I am in say, google chrome!

```
public void handle(KeyEvent ke){
    if("R".equals(ke.getText().toUpperCase() ) ) {
        if(cb.isSelected()) {
            cb.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            cb.setSelected(true);
        }
    if(cb.isSelected() == true) {
```

Comment: your post does not give idea about the framework you are using. It looks like server side framework but please mention which one is it ? Moreover you can easily do this with javascript but it will be helpful to provide answer if you mention framework.

Comment: I am doing it just in a single class on java, making a small little autoclicker that can be activated even when I am not focusing on the window. Using eclipse and javafx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As listening to keystores out of your application is system-dependent, you could use a library such as [JIintelliType](https://github.com/melloware/jintellitype)